# How to import and use images in next js?

Tags: reactjs, image, import, next.js, nextjs-image

I tried to import image using following line but it shows error:

```
import Image1 from '../public/IconGBANTQualifiedLeads.png'
```

The error I get:

> ./public/IconGBANTQualifiedLeads.png
> Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> (Source code omitted for this binary file)

Comment: What version of Next.js are you using?

Comment: "next": "^10.2.3"

Comment: Importing a local image that way without a custom webpack loader has only been introduced in Next.js 11 (https://nextjs.org/blog/next-11#image-improvements). You'll have to either upgrade to at least Next.js 11, or add a custom loader for images in your webpack config.

Answer (score 0):

NextJS has its own `Image` component you can use for this

```
import Image1 from '../public/IconGBANTQualifiedLeads.png'
import Image from 'next/image'

const Component = () => {
  return (
    <Image src={Image1} width='300px' height='200px' alt='this is my image'/>
  )
}
```

Read more about it in their docs https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image